# convert "Thu Sep 19 14:24:59 UTC 2019" to moment date

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I try to convert this date:

```
created_at= "Thu Sep 19 14:24:59 UTC 2019"
```

using this:

```
let elementDate=moment(created_at)
```

but I am getting:

```
moment.invalid(/* Fri Aug 30 09:52:04 UTC 2019 */)
```

I also tried this:

```
moment(created_at,"DDD Mo DD hh:mm:ss UTC YYYY")
```

but seems that it is not correct. Any thoughts?

Comment: I dont know anything about moment but generally month is `MM` not `Mo`. What do you mean by "seems that is not correct." Does it error or produce an unexpected effect?

Comment: @Marie is right, and "Fri" is `ddd` not `DDD`. hours in 24 hour time is `HH`

Comment: `new Date("Thu Sep 19 14:24:59 UTC 2019")` works.

Comment: @dandavis - It *may* work in some implementations, but that's not spec compliant.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint: yes, but it works in webkit/v8/ff, and there's not a lot of other UAs left to worry about these days.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Moment.js docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

> Unless you specify a time zone offset, parsing a string will create a
> date in the current time zone.

If the date strings that you need to parse are all UTC, then you can simply use [`moment.utc()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) and fix your day of the week and month format tokens. Otherwise, you will have to do some additional pre-processing on your strings as it can't parse timezone abbreviations.

```js
const dt = moment.utc('Thu Sep 19 14:24:59 UTC 2019', 'ddd MMM D HH:mm:ss [UTC] YYYY');
console.log(dt.format());
// 2019-09-19T14:24:59Z
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint - thanks for the tip (edited accordingly).